# Using Socket.io, connections keep dropping

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io to do some communication between a phone and a web page, and I'm having issues with the server constantly dropping connections. I've seen a lot of other people posting about Socket.io where their connections drop after being idle for about 5 minutes or so, but this is a connection that has constant information being emitted back and forth, and the longest I've been able to maintain a connection is about 30 seconds.

The server side code I'm running is:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('create', function (room) {
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on('player-move', function(msg){
        roomId = msg['room'];
        move = msg['action'];
        socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit('player-move', move);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('someone has disconnected');
    });

});

http.listen(443, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:443');
});
```

The client side is pretty basic emit events. Here's an example:

```
$( "#arrow-left" ).on( "touchstart", function(){
    var senddata = { "room": roomId, "action": "d-l" };
    socket.emit( "player-move", senddata );
});
```

Everything seems to be running fine until 5-30 seconds after everything starts and then the connection just drops. The connection usually starts up again, but after 5-10 seconds. Has anyone had similar issue occurring? Would this potentially be an issue with the server rather than the code? I've done similar things before on different servers with Socket.io and haven't had this kind of connection issue. Any help or direction to go in would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where are your `var` declarations for your server? `roomId = `, `move = ` will define these variables in the global scope in non-strict mode, and will outright crash your server in strict mode. Where is the client getting `roomId`? if it's undefined that might also crash your server because you're basically telling the server to run `socket.broadcast.to(undefined).emit(...);`

Comment: Is there any infrastructure between client and server that might be timing out sockets?  Are you sure that your server is running constantly and not restarting?

Comment: Are you sure they're disconnecting? The connections may also be falling back to long-polling rather than a persistent connection, which can happen for a variety of reasons, and can look like it is not connected.

Comment: I'm pretty sure sure it's disconnecting. The console is logging "someone has disconnected" every time that the issue occurs. Just to cover my bases I turned off wifi on the phone, but the issue has occurred with other people as well.
I also went ahead and made sure that the roomId and move variables were declared within the scope of that function. I don't know which one was the answer, but it doesn't seem to be disconnecting any more.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with another library called `ws` and I tried to handle the disconnection method properly by deleting the specific client sending the disconnection request from a array of clients. I don't exactly know how, but it solved my problem.

```
clients = []

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    clients.push(socket);

    // above methods

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("disconnected");
        deleteFromArray(clients, socket.id);

    });
});

function deleteFromArray(arr, element) {
  position = arr.indexOf(element);
  arr.splice(position, 1);
}
```

Comment: this answer makes no sense.

Comment: Well! I am no expert and I had answered it 4 years back. It had worked for me. I don't even remember now. If you find a good answer, then you can share it with everyone.